# Script for verifying service

Tags: bash, shell-script, solaris

I am trying to get this to run and am having no luck.  I am trying to see if 2 services exist.  If they exist and they are disabled, it should return pass.  If not then fail.

```
#!/bin/bash
# echo "Reference Number~Result~Risk Rating~Service~Service Status~Startup Mode~Other Information~Last Results time"

z=$[svcs -a | grep comsat] 
y=$[svcs -a | grep comsat-udp]  

if [ "$z" = "online"* ] && [ "$y" = "online"* ]
then
       echo "SET-4555~Pass~High~~~~"
else
       echo "SET-4555~Fail~High~~~$z~"       
fi
```

Comment: This:t/TempLinux_8_.sh: line 3: svcs -a  | grep comsat: syntax error in expression (error token is &quot;comsat&quot;)
[filepath].sh: line 4: svcs -a |  grep comsat-udp: syntax error in expression (error token is &quot;comsat-udp&quot;)","

Comment: But when I run this it always passes no matter my "if" statement:

#!/bin/bash

# echo "Reference Number~Result~Risk Rating~Service~Service Status~Startup Mode~Other Information~Last Results time"

z=$(svcs -a  | grep comsat) 
y=$(svcs -a |  grep comsat-udp)  

if [ "$z" = "disabled"* ] && [ "$y" = "enabled"* ]
then
       echo "SET-4555~Pass~High~~~~"
else
       echo "SET-4555~Fail~High~~~$z|$y~"       
fi

Comment: I did that, see above and now no error but no matter what I use in the if portion it returns failed.  Is it only reading Z and not Y? and THANK YOU

Comment: I was using disabled.  Let me try offline

Comment: I finally got this to work by placing double brackets around the if variables instead of single. 
Big THANK YOU to everyone for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# echo "Reference Number~Result~Risk Rating~Service~Service Status~Startup Mode~Other Information~Last Results time"

z=$(svcs -a | grep comsat) 
y=$(svcs -a | grep comsat-udp)  

if [ "$z" == "XXX" ] && [ "$y" == "XXX" ]
then
       echo "SET-4555~Pass~High~~~~"
else
       echo "SET-4555~Fail~High~~~$z~"       
fi
```

where `XXX` means the output of the variable `z` and `y`

Comment: Appreciated.  I made the changes you suggested and it runs with no error, however, even though both are disabled in my system it is not returning a pass.  What am I missing?

Comment: `==` instead of the standard `=` is a needless Bashism here.